# How to update database on which replication is configured?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication

We have replication setup on a database and is working fine.

Now we want to update the database on publisher. So using installer we updated the database but we are getting errors like cannot update table as table is in use.

So how can we update the database which is part of replication?

Comment: What kind of update are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to insert records in some tables, alter column, update stored procedures, etc. in short DDL and DML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DML changes (insert, update, delete) will work as expected and replicate to subscribers.  By default schema changes (DDL) will be propagated to subscribers on synchronization, publication property **@replicate_ddl** must be set to true.  There are some exceptions which can be found in [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).